# Laravel loop damaged design

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I have default template which is looks like this

[image: one]

when i add my loop it becomes like this

[image: two]

## Issue

As you see in second image padding and margins are not as same as default one but html output looks fine

## here is the code

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 pad-l">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($featuresTwo as $featuret)
            @if($loop->first)
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="post-overaly-style hot-post-top clearfix">
                        <div class="post-thumb">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="theme/images/news/tech/gadget2.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a class="post-cat" href="#">
                                @foreach($featuret->categories as $categoryt)
                                {{ $loop->first ? ' ' : ', ' }}
                                {{$categoryt->title}}
                                @endforeach
                            </a>
                            <h2 class="post-title title-large">
                                <a href="#">{{$featuret->title}}</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div><!-- Post content end -->
                    </div><!-- Post Overaly end -->
                </div><!-- Col end -->
            @else
                <div class="col-sm-6 pad-r-small">
                    <div class="post-overaly-style hot-post-bottom clearfix">
                        <div class="post-thumb">
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="theme/images/news/lifestyle/travel2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a class="post-cat" href="#">
                                @foreach($featuret->categories as $categoryt)
                                    {{ $loop->first ? ' ' : ', ' }}
                                    {{$categoryt->title}}
                                @endforeach
                            </a>
                            <h2 class="post-title title-medium">
                                <a href="#">{{$featuret->title}}</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div><!-- Post content end -->
                    </div><!-- Post Overaly end -->
                </div><!-- Col end -->
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div><!-- Col 5 end -->
```

## Question

Where did I make mistake? How to fix it?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

original html without loop

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 pad-l">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="post-overaly-style hot-post-top clearfix">
            <div class="post-thumb">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/news/tech/gadget2.jpg" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-content">
                <a class="post-cat" href="#">Gadget</a>
                <h2 class="post-title title-large">
                    <a href="#">Samsung Gear S3 review: A whimper, when smartwatches need a bang</a>
                </h2>
            </div><!-- Post content end -->
        </div><!-- Post Overaly end -->
        </div><!-- Col end -->

        <div class="col-sm-6 pad-r-small">
        <div class="post-overaly-style hot-post-bottom clearfix">
            <div class="post-thumb">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/news/lifestyle/travel2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-content">
                <a class="post-cat" href="#">Travel</a>
                <h2 class="post-title title-medium">
                    <a href="#">Early tourists choices to the sea of Maldiv…</a>
                </h2>
            </div><!-- Post content end -->
        </div><!-- Post Overaly end -->
        </div><!-- Col end -->

        <div class="col-sm-6 pad-l-small">
        <div class="post-overaly-style hot-post-bottom clearfix">
            <div class="post-thumb">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/news/lifestyle/health1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-content">
                <a class="post-cat" href="#">Health</a>
                <h2 class="post-title title-medium">
                    <a href="#">That wearable on your wrist could soon...</a>
                </h2>
            </div><!-- Post content end -->
        </div><!-- Post Overaly end -->
        </div><!-- Col end -->
    </div>
</div><!-- Col 5 end -->
```

........................................................................................................................

Comment: do you have the original html without the loops for comparison?

Comment: @wheelmaker yed i do, i'll update my question.

Comment: @wheelmaker updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

Based on `wheelmaker` answer i got the idea and changed my div after `@else` to be like

```
@if($loop->last)
  <div class="col-sm-6 pad-l-small">
@else
  <div class="col-sm-6 pad-r-small">
@endif
```

and that solved the style issue.

> PS: I'm accepting `wheelmaker` answer because he made me realized the
>   issue.

Answer (score 2):

The original code for the two half width columns has one like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 pad-r-small">
```

And one like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pad-l-small">
```

But you've used a loop to create two of the same like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pad-r-small">
```

You should probably just key the features in the `$featuresTwo` array and drop the loops so you can replicate the code accurately.

Comment: You could of course keep track of where you're at in the loop and change the class accordingly but I think this is an instance of over complicating things in order to avoid any amount of duplication and will just get more complicated if/when these divs require any further changes.

Comment: thanks man, i got the idea but i've done it other way and it's fixed now :-D

Comment: Accepted your answer and posted the solution ;)